# Explanation on iptables packets

Tags: iptables

I'm a little confused with source and destination ports and addresses

I tried looking on forums but there's people saying both input is source and output has a source so is it

```
Iptables -A INPUT --source 192.168.1.124 -j DROP

iptables -A OUTPUT --Destination 192.168.1.123 -j DROP
```

Or is it this

```
Iptables -A INPUT --destination 192.168.1.123 -j DROP

iptables -A OUTPUT --source 192.168.1.123 -j DROP
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The INPUT chain of rules is only applied to packets into the local host, and the OUTPUT chain only for packets that leave the local host. Both are applied, however, to loopback packets. In that respect, there is a difference between `iptables` and the older `ipchains` which has more or less the same syntax.

For basic use like dropping incoming packets, specifying `source` makes sense with the INPUT chain only, and `destination` only with OUTPUT chain.

See the [man page](http://ipset.netfilter.org/iptables.man.html) and play around if you have the chance.

Comment: So you're saying it can be either, INPUT source and INPUT destination do the same thing

Comment: No, I'm saying that specifying a destination in an INPUT chain makes no sense, unless you are going to forward that packet later. For a regular system with a single network interface that doesn't do routing, you would only use INPUT with `source`, and OUTPUT with `destination`.